# Anyone know how to recover this video from PhotoBooth?

Tags: recording, photo-booth

I've tried using both VLC and HandBrake to retrieve this video. It says that its duration is 0 mins and 0 seconds but the file size is 205.4 MB. It is a presentation for my speech class anything helps. [image: picture of the error message]

Comment: Try looking up video repair tools. There are online versions, program versions, free ones, paid-for ones

Comment: Do you have any recommendations on which one is best for my situation?

Comment: I've known StellarPhoenixVideoRepair to fix a video nothing else could, but I've only tested it on a sample size of one.